# How can I add a "weight" functionality to nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes

I would like to be able to specify a "weight" for the article nodes published in the homepage. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Comparison of Node/Entity Ordering Modules https://www.drupal.org/node/398508

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could for example use [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) to create  fixed list of nodes and then show that as the front page (as a view I guess).

Or, you could define your own weight field (for example a simple integer field, or a select with options from -50  to 50) and then create a [view](http://drupal.org/project/views) of nodes which you sort based on that field.

Comment: +1 on Nodequeues.  You can also do a view over a nodequeue, which can be handy.

Comment: Nodequeue looks interesting, I'll check it out. If I decide to go with the second option, how could I sort by this field the nodes of my homepage and possibly also the administration content area? are we talking a custom module and DB queries?

Comment: You are looking for http://drupal.org/project/views

Answer (score 5):

Both [Draggeble Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) and [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) are great for creating easy-to-use admin pages with drag-and-drop sorting. The main difference between Draggable Views and Nodequeue is that Nodequeue allows manual sorting *and selection*, whereas Draggable Views allows manual sorting of an automatically populated list (a view). Both modules are explained and compared in [these](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/arbitrarily-order-your-views-part-1-draggableviews) [two](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/arbitrarily-order-your-views-part-2-nodequeue) blog posts.